# How does Terraform know that randomly named resources already exist?

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Consider the following Terraform template:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurecaf = {
      source = "aztfmod/azurecaf"
      version = "1.2.23"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurecaf_name" "rg_name" {
  name            = var.appname
  resource_type   = "azurerm_resource_group"
  prefixes        = ["dev"]
  suffixes        = ["y", "z"]
  random_length   = 5   // <------ random part in name generation
  clean_input     = false
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = azurecaf_name.rg_name.result
  location = var.resource_group_location
}
```

I applied this template, than ran `terraform plan`. Terraform plan tells me

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

How does that work as `azurecaf_name.rg_name` contains random characters? I would have expected it to create a new resource group with a new (random) name. I know that Terraform keeps a state, but doesn't it execute the template every time (=new random name) and then checks if that matches state and real resources in cloud?

Comment: Terraform generated the random name **once** and stored that in the state file. The next time you run Terraform it looks in the state file for `azurecaf_name.rg_name` in the state file, finds it there, uses the name that is stored in there to look it up in Azure and finds that it still exists in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The random characters are stored in the state file along with the other attributes of the resource like `random_length`, `prefixes`, `suffixes`. When you rerun terraform it will first check have any of the attributes in your configuration changed from whats in the state file. In your case all the values like `random_length` are the same. So terraform knows it doesnt need to regenerate anything like the random attributes since your configuration has not changed. Terraform will then check the state of the resource in the remote provider using the resource ID generated by the remote provider. If it doesnt exist terraform will create it with the same data. if it does exist but its attributes dont match then it will update the resource. if it checks its values there match whats in the state file. If they are the same then terraform knows no changes are needed.

We can see this in the `random_pet` resource

```
resource "random_pet" "foo" {
  length = 3
  prefix = "foo"
}
```

**State file**

```json
"resources": [
    {
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "random_pet",
      "name": "foo",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "id": "foo-evidently-secure-killdeer",
            "keepers": null,
            "length": 3,
            "prefix": "foo",
            "separator": "-"
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Normally resources that have a form of randomness